# post_receive hook in git: how does it checkouts my non-git folder?

Tags: django, git, webfaction, git-post-receive, git-reset

I am using `webfaction` for my `web deployment`.

I have a Django app at: webapps/django_app/project_name/

I have a Git repo at: webapps/git_app/repos/my_repo.git

my_repo.git is a bare repository. It is not a working directory.

whenever I push from my local development computer to the remote (webfaction --> my_repo.git), I want my django_app to get the pushed code.

I followed this [post](https://community.webfaction.com/questions/1246/using-git-with-applications) which works fine. But no explanation of how this works is given.

I have added these two lines in `post_recieve` hook in my_repo.git.

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/username/webapps/django/myproject git checkout -f 
GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/username/webapps/django/myproject git reset --hard
```

what does this two lines actually do?

Moreover, my Djangoapp folder is not a git repo. still whenever push is made to my_repo.git, Djangoapp gets updated. so how does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are managing files locally with `.git`, you typically have two things:

- Your git repository, which is contained in the `.git` directory, and
- Your work tree, which is the set of files you are actually editing.

By default, the repository is a subdirectory of the work tree, but this is not a requirement.  Setting the `GIT_WORK_TREE` environment variable directs git to use a different location for your checkout out files.

So the first line...

```
GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/username/webapps/django/myproject git checkout -f
```

...is asking git to check out the `HEAD` of the repository into `/home/username/webapps/django/myproject`.

The second line...

```
GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/username/webapps/django/myproject git reset --hard
```

...makes sure that `/home/username/webapps/django/myproject` does not have any local changes.  `reset --hard` discards any changes to files that are tracked by git. By "local changes" I mean any changes that you or someone else has made to files in this directory; ideally, there won't be any, but if there were some there, `reset -f` makes sure that the modified files are overwritten with the version of the file stored in the repository.

For more details on any of the commands listed here, try running `git <command> --help` for the man page, or see [The Git Book](http://git-scm.com/book).

Comment: thanks.  `/home/username/webapps/django/myproject` is not a git repo. It is just a directory. can I still checkout into it? secondly. I tried google to find what checkout -f mean? but did not find a good answer. what is it exactly? why is there no branch name followed i.e git checkout -f master?

Comment: and you say `makes sure that /home/username/webapps/django/myproject does not have any local changes.` , where do any local changes can come from? what does reset exactly do? some example? Thank you very much

Comment: To find out what `checkout -f` means, try `git checkout --help`.

Comment: I've updated the answer to hopefully address your other questions.